# How to run Webdriver headless with Chrome profiles

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have been use Chrome profiles to login a website it was success...! But want to browser not showing up so I added `options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+myProfilesPath);` after then it not working! Plzz tell me why headless argument not working with profiles? And How do I solve that problem?

Comment: you need to add: options.addArguments("--headless");

Comment: Yes I did it, but add: options.addArguments("--headless"); not working with options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+myProfilesPath);

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);
WebDriver driver  = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```